# Is there a way to get the "Watch Later" playlist using YouTube API v3?

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was wondering if this is available in v3 (I know it's possible with v2)?

I've tried using watch_later as the id and `mine=true` in a playlist request.  The watch_later playlist is not returned in the generic playlists list results when specifying `mine=true`.

Comment: This is no longer possible as mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239503/youtube-data-api-v3-playlistitems-update-not-working-for-watch-later-playlists).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76493716) is a web scraping solution.

Answer (score 16):

## Update

[As of Sep 12 2016](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#august-11-2016), watch later and watch history can no longer be retrieved YouTube Data API v3.

## Original answer (no longer works)

You can get the IDs of you special private playlists with an authenticated request to

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

One of these is your *watchLater* playlist. Note the playlist id and use it in another authenticated request to get a list of all items on your *watchLater* list:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: this doesn't work anymore (see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-15-2016)