# How to get watched history of YouTube user using Youtube JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am able to get search results, playlists of an user using YouTube Javascript API.

How can I get the watched history of an user using YouTube JavaScript API???

Is there any JavaScript API to get the YouTube watched history of an user??

Comment: This is no longer possible, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987690/tracking-youtube-watch-history) answer. Google deprecated the ability to see watch history and watch later. Wanted comment on this ticket as I searched around for a little while to find this answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the general procedure:

1. Get the "watch History" playlist of a given user's channel (as a channel ID is the key to getting user info). Note that this will ONLY work when a user is authenticated via oAuth2.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

With that response, there should be a "watchHistory" playlist ... take it and call the playlistItems endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=HLTFxEo9ofKM2Siifxoy5V_A&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Unfortunately, many users are reporting there's a bug in the watch history playlist through the API right now:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642

So your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks For your help!!! I have got the watched history of  a particular user from following code:                                                                     function handleAPILoaded() {
     var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
        mine: true,
        part: 'contentDetails'
    });
    request.execute(function (response) {
        debugger;
        playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory;
        requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId);
    });

}

Comment: And i need one more help...How can i get the categories of watched videos from watchHistory.. I want the category based watched videos.. I will be more helpfull for me I you give answer for this query. I thank you for your help..

Comment: @user3062437 In my case, the request what you suggested to get playlist id for watch history returned wrong playlist id ("HL"). Of course, when send api for detail with the wrong playlist id("HL") returned empty list. Google work for us plz...

Answer (score 36):

This no longer seems possible with the V3 API. The watchHistory playlist ID is now always set to 'HL'.

Comment: It looks like Google blocked access to the watch history: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35172816.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a Python script retrieving `Watch Later` playlist content.

Note that `SAPISIDHASH`, `__Secure_3PSID` and `__Secure_3PAPISID` values have to be changed thanks to loading on your web-browser [the `Watch Later` webpage](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL) resulting in a curl request interacting with the same URL (and https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse for getting `SAPISIDHASH` after having scrolled the first 100 results) in your web browser `Network` developer tools tab.

```py
import requests, json

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL'

__Secure_3PSID = '__Secure_3PSID.'
# Note that `__Secure_3PAPISID`, `headers`, `cookies` and `context` aren't needed for just listing first 100 videos from `Watch Later` playlist.
__Secure_3PAPISID = '__Secure_3PAPISID'
SAPISIDHASH = 'SAPISIDHASH'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.youtube.com',
    'Authorization': f'SAPISIDHASH {SAPISIDHASH}'
}
cookies = {
    '__Secure-3PSID': __Secure_3PSID,
    '__Secure-3PAPISID': __Secure_3PAPISID
}
context = {
    'client': {
        'clientName': 'WEB',
        'clientVersion': '2.20230613.01.00'
    }
}

content = requests.get(url, cookies = cookies).text
content = content.split('">var ytInitialData = ')[1].split(';</script>')[0]
data = json.loads(content)

def treatContents(contents):
    MAX_RESULTS = 100
    for content in contents[:MAX_RESULTS]:
        playlistVideoRenderer = content['playlistVideoRenderer']
        videoId = playlistVideoRenderer['videoId']
        title = playlistVideoRenderer['title']['runs'][0]['text']
        print(videoId, title)
    # If response contains a `token` for retrieving additional pages, let's continue.
    if len(contents) > MAX_RESULTS:
        token = contents[MAX_RESULTS]['continuationItemRenderer']['continuationEndpoint']['continuationCommand']['token']

        url = 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse'
        data = {
            'context': context,
            'continuation': token
        }

        data = requests.post(url, headers = headers, cookies = cookies, json = data).json()
        continuationItems = data['onResponseReceivedActions'][0]['appendContinuationItemsAction']['continuationItems']
        treatContents(continuationItems)

contents = data['contents']['twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer']['tabs'][0]['tabRenderer']['content']['sectionListRenderer']['contents'][0]['itemSectionRenderer']['contents'][0]['playlistVideoListRenderer']['contents']

treatContents(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Google blocked access to the watch history (via YouTube Data API v3): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35172816.