# How to get youtube watch history programatically in Android

Tags: android

How to read youtube watched history in android? i have read youtube API told that google has blocked history API but some of the like **kidslox** and some parental child control app showing youtube history. any specific permission is required to read watched you tube history?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30849715/6997819 Chek if this helps.

Comment: @VirRajpurohit but as per google document using v3 API google history has been deprecate