# Get list of all comments made by a given user with YouTube Data API?

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get a list of all comments made by a given user's account with YouTube Data API, or even another API?

If this isn't a direct feature, would there be a convoluted way of doing this by seeing all the videos watched by a user and parsing the comments out of those specific videos?

The goal of my project is to create a 'Spotify Wrapped' style website but for YouTube (showing a user their most liked comments, the channels they watch the most, etc) but I'm having trouble finding the correct search criteria in the YouTube Data API documentation.

I am using HMTL, CSS, and JavaScript currently, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: Because of privacy issues, I am **guessing** that this type of search is not allowed. It does have interesting potential, but with the billions of videos, comments, etc that would be a search engine all to itself e.g. would be expensive for Google to provide for free.

Comment: It is unclear whether or not you assume having access to the user OAuth2 token to use YouTube APIs or that the user would execute some code to web-scrap https://myactivity.google.com/page?page=youtube_comments Otherwise [I retrieved all comments from all French videos](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-comments-graph) to then filter a user out of this dataset, it may interest you.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Thanks! I'd be ok with using the OAuth2 token, I'll take a look at this, filtering a user out of a large dataset will probably be the path i have to take. I have heard there was a way to get a user's search history, and that could be the set of comments i look through, but that [apparently no longer works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849284/how-to-get-watched-history-of-youtube-user-using-youtube-javascript-api)

Comment: Ridiculous that [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) works for liked videos (LL) but not for watch later (WL), [WH](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WH)/HL not working on my end from the YT UI. Anyway I strongly recommend you that if you assume to have the user's OAuth2 token to just use web-scraping [on this webpage](https://myactivity.google.com/page?page=youtube_comments). Getting the YouTube dataset is a nightmare and I guess YT will do everything to avoid you to do so.