# How to Add All Videos from a Channel to a Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

According to [this answer [1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533246/4756173), *YouTube Watch Later* access through YouTube API v3 seems very limited, so I think I'm going to restrict this question to adding to a playlist instead.

> Even though YouTube API v3 doesn't seem to work with Watch Later, [the PocketTube browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pockettube-youtube-subscr/kdmnjgijlmjgmimahnillepgcgeemffb) seems to be able to access and manage it. How does it do it? Maybe it's using v2 or v1? Some operations on PocketTube seem much slower than expected.

Anyways, this is what I think the workflow to achieve this would be:

1. Loop through the pages of videos in a channel with YouTube API. Something like this:

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&key={{YOUTUBE_API_KEY}}&forUsername={{CHANNEL_USERNAME}}&order=date&maxResults=50
   ```

   But I'm getting a weird response like this (I used [Veritasium's channel](https://www.youtube.com/@veritasium) for this example):

   ```json
   {
       "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
       "etag": "rKBMFgDUZ01YcV1szgI433m_NI4",
       "pageInfo": {
           "totalResults": 1,
           "resultsPerPage": 50
       },
       "items": [
           {
               "kind": "youtube#channel",
               "etag": "fdmldzetq8235Eh_T--brsjat6M",
               "id": "UCHnyfMqiRRG1u-2MsSQLbXA",
               "contentDetails": {
                   "relatedPlaylists": {
                       "likes": "",
                       "uploads": "UUHnyfMqiRRG1u-2MsSQLbXA"
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Use YouTube API to add all videos to a playlist (need OAuth key?). Is it even possible?

If you can, I would greatly appreciate a script for this. I personally typically use TypeScript or Bash for doing these types of scripts, but whatever language will suffice.

---

### References

1. [Is there a way to get the "Watch Later" playlist using YouTube API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533246/4756173)
2. [YouTube API to fetch all videos on a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18953499)

   - The answers on this one seem very odd, cause the question is about all videos on a channel, but the answers are mostly about all videos in playlists.

Comment: For adding videos to [`Watch Later` playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL) consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970181), for fetching all videos on a channel consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030), for getting the `Watch Later` playlist consider [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891357/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-watch-later-playlist-using-youtube-api-v3#comment135853183_15891357).

Comment: There is also the [Multiselect for YouTube browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiselect-for-youtube/gpgbiinpmelaihndlegbgfkmnpofgfei/related), which probably uses JS to select the videos visually and then does some batch operation on it.

Comment: I think I'm gonna change this question to "add to playlist" instead of "add to Watch Later", since it doesn't seem possible. Then I can use the Multiselect for YouTube to manually move them to Watch Later.

Comment: I don't get it: isn't [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77059978/how-to-add-all-videos-from-a-channel-to-a-playlist#comment135853185_77059978) meeting your needs? (as you added a bounty)